# LPWAN technologies and Dash7

Tags: bluetooth, lora, lpwan, sigfox

I need to transfer messages from node to gateway that would be at most 2km apart.

- I am currently working with 40 nodes that wake up every 1 minute. So I would like to have battery life of at least 3-5 years.
- I would like to have 95% accuracy from the node.
- A fully bi-directional messaging feature is the goal.

I have worked with bluetooth, LoRa and sigfox. Unfortunately none of them worked well either due to range or one-directional messaging capability.

I am interested to work with Haystack Dash7 and looking into development boards. I am  unable to find user reviews on Dash7 online. Hence, I would like to know from Dash7 users if they think Dash7 would fit the aforementioned requirements and what development board would be better to start with? If not, what LPWAN technology you would suggest?